# Como filtrar vários itens dentro de um array

Tags: javascript, array, filter

Eu tenho o seguinte JSON:

```
{
    "Empresas": [{
      "Name": "DIST",
      "Portais": [{
        "title": "PRD",
        "tags": ["PRD", "DIST1"]
      },{
        "title": "HIST",
        "tags": ["PCP", "DIST2", "DIST3"]
        }]
    },
     {"Name": "LUZ",
       "Portais": [{
         "title": "QA",
         "tags": ["QA", "LUZ"]
       }]
     }]
}
```

No meu `navbar` tem uma barra de pesquisa, que no momento só está filtrando uma tag, eu queria pesquisar por várias. *Ex: "PCP DIST2"*.

Segue parte do código abaixo:

```
this.portais.forEach( (e: Empresa) => {
    var novoElemento = Object();
    novoElemento.Name = e.Name;

    novoElemento.Portais = e.Portais.filter(item => item.tags.find(i => i.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase())> -1));

    this.output_portais.push(novoElemento);

});
```

A variável `'val'` se refere ao valor digitado no campo de pesquisa.

Comment: Filtrar mais de um, você quer procurar ambos (AND) ou qualquer um dos digitados (OU)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se for digitado `"PCP DIST2"`, você quer que filtre os elementos que tem **ambas as tags** "PCP" e "DIST2", ou pode ser os elementos que tenham **pelo menos uma delas**?

---

Independente do critério, uma forma de resolver é primeiro quebrar as tags em um array, usando [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) (mas antes uso [`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) para transformá-las em minúsculas, pois vi que você quer fazer a consulta *case insensitive*, além de [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) para remover os espaços do início e fim da string, caso contrário o `split` retornará strings vazias no array):

```js
let val = 'PCP DIST2';
let valores = val.trim().toLowerCase().split(' ');
console.log(valores); // ["pcp", "dist2"]

// se estiver separado por mais de um espaço, use:
val = '  PCP    DIST2  ';
valores = val.trim().toLowerCase().split(/\s+/);
console.log(valores); // ["pcp", "dist2"]
```

Em seguida, temos que decidir o critério. Se quisermos verificar que ambas as tags estão no array, temos que usar [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) (que verifica se todos os elementos satisfazem o critério). Mas se quisermos que qualquer uma das tags (
mas não necessariamente todas) estejam no array, usamos [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) (que verifica se algum dos elementos satisfaz o critério). E para verificar se o elemento está no array, usamos [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). Alguns exemplos:

```js
let val = 'PCP DIST2';
let valores = val.trim().toLowerCase().split(' ');

// verificando se todas as tags estão no array
// array contém PCP e DIST2
console.log(valores.every(valor => ['PCP', 'ABC', 'DIST2'].map(s => s.toLowerCase()).includes(valor))); // true 
// array contém PCP, mas não DIST2
console.log(valores.every(valor => ['PCP', 'ABC', 'DIST1'].map(s => s.toLowerCase()).includes(valor))); // false 
// array não contém PCP nem DIST2
console.log(valores.every(valor => ['PC', 'ABC', 'DIST1'].map(s => s.toLowerCase()).includes(valor))); // false 

// verificando se alguma das tags está no array
// array contém PCP, mas não DIST2
console.log(valores.some(valor => ['PCP', 'ABC', 'DIST1'].map(s => s.toLowerCase()).includes(valor))); // true 
// array contém DIST2, mas não PCP
console.log(valores.some(valor => ['PC', 'ABC', 'DIST2'].map(s => s.toLowerCase()).includes(valor))); // true 
// array não contém PCP nem DIST2
console.log(valores.some(valor => ['PC', 'ABC', 'DIST1'].map(s => s.toLowerCase()).includes(valor))); // false
```

Ou seja, para todos os valores da busca, eu verifico se todos (ou se algum deles, depende do critério) estão no array de tags.

Claro que você poderia usar [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), que retorna o índice do elemento (ou -1 se este não existir no array), mas como você só quer saber se o elemento existe ou não, usar `includes` é mais direto, pois retorna apenas `true` ou `false`.

Outro detalhe é que [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) retorna um array vazio caso não encontre nenhum elemento que satisfaça o critério. Então você deve verificar se o array retornado está vazio antes de adicioná-lo nos resultados.

Sendo assim, no seu caso ficaria:

```
// para verificar se todas as tags estão no array
this.portais.forEach( (e: Empresa) => {
    var novoElemento = Object();
    novoElemento.Name = e.Name;
    novoElemento.Portais = e.Portais.filter(item => valores.every(valor => item.tags.map(s => s.toLowerCase()).includes(valor)));
    if (novoElemento.Portais.length > 0) { // só insiro se encontrou algum
        this.output_portais.push(novoElemento);
    }
});

// para verificar se alguma das tags está no array
this.portais.forEach( (e: Empresa) => {
    var novoElemento = Object();
    novoElemento.Name = e.Name;
    novoElemento.Portais = e.Portais.filter(item => valores.some(valor => item.tags.map(s => s.toLowerCase()).includes(valor)));
    if (novoElemento.Portais.length > 0) { // só insiro se encontrou algum
        this.output_portais.push(novoElemento);
    }
});
```

Repare também no uso de [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) para ter o array de tags todo em minúsculas.

Comment: A minha intenção era filtrar os elementos que tem ambas as tags, muito obrigada pela explicação, eu alterei aqui e funcionou exatamente como eu queria :)